# Postfix Email Rejected

Tags: networking, server, email, postfix, mail

Postfix rejects all incoming emails. I have Virtualmin as installed as a frontend for managing and I'm hosting multiple domains on that machine - emails for all domains are rejected. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and Postix 2.11.0.

As an error I'm seeing this in `/var/log/mail.log`

```
Sep 13 16:49:56 hostname.tld postfix/cleanup[20030]: warning: 411BA1245DB: unreasonable virtual_alias_maps map nesting for email@domain.tld -- message not accepted, try again later
```

In `mydestination` I have

```
 mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, XXX
```

which seems to be ok (XXX = domainname.tld of hosted domains on the server)

The nondefault values of `/etc/postifx/main.cf` (`postconf -n`) are

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, djp-web.de, pa-galli.de
myhostname = djp-web.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks     permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated     defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

in `/etc/postfix/virtual` everything seems ok, too. Just a bunch of entries like

```
domain.tld   domain.tld
user@domain.tld   some.other.email@gmail.com
domain.tld   [name of corrosponding unix user]
user@domain.tld   [name of corrosponding unix user]
@domain.tld   some.other.email@gmail.com
```

I already posted this question in the Virtualmin Forum but no one did know an answer to it. In fact it was recommended to ask a Ubuntu Community. https://www.virtualmin.com/node/37986

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/postfix/virtual` remove or edit these lines:

```
domain.tld   domain.tld
domain.tld   [name of corrosponding unix user]
```

I am not sure what you want them to do, but it is not how it is done, the domain.tld should either start with `@` or not be there at all, first line does not make sense, see http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html

Comment: I deleted them, reloaded postfix (even did a reboot) but nothing changes. Still the same error.

Comment: You can check in some text editor for hidden character,  typo, or infinite loop against logic. Maybe try adding lines one by one - postfix reload is enough, no need to restart.

Comment: I just `echo "" > virtual` and then added one email adress as `user@domain.tld    my.own.email@gmail.com` as a simple redirect. Won't work either.

Comment: Is it still giving you the `... unreasonable virtual_alias_maps map nesting ... ` error? That is what we are solving I hope?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same error.